# DataGridView DateTime Picker Cells Automatic Value Adding

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I wish to setup one of my columns in my DataGridView in such a way that than when the user edits a cell in this column, a DateTime Picker appears. I copied the required classes to do so from [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80.aspx) MSDN post. When I Fill my DataGridView with data, I do so by using the following code :

```
   MySqlDataAdapter daClients = new MySqlDataAdapter(sql, cnManageMembers);
            daClients.Fill(dtClients);

            BindingSource bsClients = new BindingSource();
            bsClients.DataSource = dtClients;
            dgvClients.DataSource = bsClients;
            bnClients.BindingSource = bsClients;
```

This method of filling uses a BindingSource to Fill the DataGridView and that automatically takes care of things like adding the required columns and cells, however I need to change one of the columns manner of editing their cells.What code can I implement so that I do not have to manually add every Cell and it's value.So instead of this(taken from the MSDN post):

```
    DataTable dtClients = new DataTable();
    CalendarColumn col = new CalendarColumn();
    this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
    this.dataGridView1.RowCount = 5;
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataGridView1.Rows)
    {
        row.Cells[0].Value = DateTime.Now;
    }
```

Is there a way to replace the Default Cell the BindingSource adds with the custom Calender Cell(Perhaps in the DrawCell EventHandler?).

Comment: try this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7tas5c80(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: That's the link I used, still requires manually adding values